# Drawing animated lines

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make the Logo Turtle in HTML 5 with javascript and canvas (I want to study simple algorithms with my students, and i want to make easy instructions).

I successfully made basic instructions, but the lines appear all at the same time, and i want to see them appear one after one.

Here is my code :

```js
var dessin = document.getElementById("dessin")
var ctx = dessin.getContext("2d");

var angle = 0; // angle en degrés
// on donne les coordonnées de départ
var x = dessin.width / 2;
var y = dessin.height / 2;

function forward(distance) {
  var iter = 1;
  var Angle = angle % 360;
  var theta = Angle / 180 * Math.PI;
  var vitesse = 10;
  var compteur = 1;

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    x = Math.cos(theta) * distance / vitesse + x;
    y = Math.sin(theta) * distance / vitesse + y;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    compteur++;
    if (compteur > vitesse) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

  }, 1000 / vitesse);
  //setTimeout(clearInterval(timer),2000);
}

function turn_left(angle_rotation) {
  angle = (angle - angle_rotation) % 360;
}


//Firing commands
turn_left(45);
forward(100);
turn_left(45);
forward(100);
```

```html
<canvas id="dessin" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I want to have two lines (a diagonal one, and a vertical one), but i have lot of it...

How can i do that ?

Thanks !
PS : I don't speak English very well, my apologies...

Comment: not related to your main question, but consider doing `angle = (angle + 360 - angle_rotation) % 360` to ensure that your angles remain positive

Comment: I think you'll struggle to get useful answers here, because what you need is relatively difficult.  Your turtle instructions, instead of immediately performing actions, need to add the intended action to a _queue_ of things to do.  At each frame (i.e. using `window.requestAnimationFrame`) you'd need to examine the queue, and the progress of the current action, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your code is asynchrone. To achieve what you want to do, you need an animations manager.

Here, our animations manager is just two var : one is a boolean to know if we are moving, another is an array which accumulates queued animations:

```
var moveManager = [];
var isMoving = false;
```

I also make timer global because we have only one animation at a time :

```
var timer;
```

After you need to make the logic of your animations manager which is : If i'm not moving and I have a queued animation so play it :

```
function nextMove() {
        if (!isMoving && moveManager.length) {
            var move = moveManager.shift();
            move();
    }
}
```

And, last thing, each animation manages itself start, stop and call to next animation :

```
function turn_left(angle_rotation) {
    moveManager.push(function() {
    isMoving = true;
    angle = (angle - angle_rotation) % 360 ;
    isMoving = false;
    nextMove();
  });
}
```

With all this, you can continue your turtle.

Working jsFiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/y9efewqb/5/

PS : I use your code to explain how to make your turle but some part should be optimized (use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of using `setInterval`, make all this in classes to avoid global var, ...)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot !!!

I think classes are a bit too difficult for me now, but in the future...

Comment: It works as is. PS part is just some improvement points. However, I'm glad to help you

Comment: I have an other question :

I want to add two functions : pen_off() and pen_on() : pen_on() makes a boolean true and the line is drawn, pen_off() makes this boolean false and the line is not drawn, there is a jump (to make dashed lines for example).

Comment: See this updated jsfiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/y9efewqb/7/ . To make `pen_on/pen_off` work, I added another var which test if I draw or if I just update x/y position

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly !

I've tried to create a such variable, but i don't succeed.

I have a lot to learn.